# Creating a collapsible navigation bar in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I wish to create a collapsible navigation like the one shown in the video linked below (the screen cast is for the android version of the app).
[screencast](https://youtu.be/kfPoFUhMoYw)

I'd like to know what classes I should use to accomplish this effect. Also note that the tagline "I am the founder" can vary in length so the expanded layout can vary in length. How would I be able to size the expanded nav bar dynamically (the only example I found had static sizes for the expanded and contracted states)?

Answer (score 0):

Cool question. The best way I can think of would be to not use a navigation bar. Best would be to use a UITableView, have three cells, as shown here:

[image]

When the user scrolls and the top cell disappears, you can animate out the second cell as shown in the video using custom animation and viewWillDisappear (tableView protocol function).

Then have a fourth cell you design that appears. This fourth cell is the navigation bar that the user sees after scrolling. Keep this cell at the top until the user scrolls to the top.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose, you can use 3rd party cocoa pod. The link is given below. 
https://github.com/vicentesuarez/Swift-FlexibleHeightBar